# <bound method class.method of <Class: >>

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

This is my models.py:

```
Class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.surname)

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s profile"

    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.surname}"

class Composition(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} {self.composer.full_name}"
```

I can't understand why I'm getting `Title <bound method Profile.full_name of <Profile: MyName's profile>>` in the Django admin site, in the list of compositions' titles. Calling `self.composer.full_name()` only gets me two `<bound method...>` items. Can someone please help me? I've been battling with this for a while now and I'm stuck.

PS:

clicking on it returns:

```
TypeError at /admin/nms_app/composition/3/change/
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

PS2:

adding `@property` doesn't help.

**Solution:**

Thanks to Suh Fangmbeng I realised that I forgot a 'user' in the Profile class's method:

```
    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.surname}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes to your Profile model like so:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s profile"

    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.surname}"
```

Then Use:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title} {self.composer.full_name()}"
```

Instead of:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title} {self.composer.full_name}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd updated my question before seeing your answer. Doing that only adds yet another <bound method> message!

Comment: I get TypeError at /admin/nms_app/composition/3/change/ - 'str' object is not callable if I do that (and thanks for spotting the missing 'user' bit! My bad.)

Comment: It actually works without parenthesis: return f"{self.title} {self.composer.full_name()}" . The issue was the missing 'user' in '{self.user.first_name}' and '{self.user.surname'}.

Comment: you no longer need `self.composer.full_name()` because you added @property. Note that the @property frequently can lead too much caching and unnecessary memory use

Comment: Still, if I call self.composer.full_name() I get "'str' object is not callable". Just for science :)

Comment: Yes, if you remove @property, you won't get that error